# Regarding atomicity of Python statements and Global Interpreter Lock

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I read somewhere that indexing a list e.g. l[3] is an atomic operation. Is the atomicity achieved because of global interpreter lock.

Comment: Related: [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm)

Comment: @unutbu: yeah, I stumbled across that, too, but its age is unknown and I can't verify whether it applies to modern Python, too.

Comment: @unutbu: official py2.7 source: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe Closing sentence: **When in doubt, use a mutex!**

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Thanks for the link to the docs. It also applies to CPython3: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indexing **should** be atomic, as long as you do it on a native list, and not one where someone could have redirected `__getitem__`; however, that's an *implementation detail*, and you can't rely on it.

No, it's not solely because of the GIL, but because switching between threads is only allowed between single interpreter instructions, and indexing is such a single instruction, but only in CPython.

Takeaway: **Do not rely on atomicity in a high level scripting language such as python**; if you need barriers, then use semaphores or explicitly atomic data types.